# This is my php code corresponding to my application.I don't get what's wrong with this that the result gives failure instead of success

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my php code corresponding to my application.I don't get what's wrong with this that the result gives failure instead of success

```
<?php

    $fname = @$_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = @$_POST['lastname'];
    $email = @$_POST['email'];
    $contact = @$_POST['contact'];

    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','three');

    if($con->connect_error){
        echo 'database connection error';
    }

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO detail (firstname, lastname, email, contact) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("sssi",$fname,$lname,$email,$contact);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        echo 'success' ;

    } else {

        echo 'failure' ;

    }
?>
```

html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> PHP Database Example with Ajax</title>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> Enter Details </h1>
            <form method= 'post' action='detail.php'>
                <p> First Name </p>
                <input type = "text" id='fname' name = "firstname" placeholder = "Enter your first name" /><br><br><br>
                <p> Last Name </p>
                <input type = "text" id='lname' name = "lastname" placeholder = "Enter your Last name" /><br><br><br>
                <p> Email Id  </p>
                <input type = "text" id='email' name = "email" placeholder = "Enter your Email Address" /><br><br><br>
                <p> Contact Number </p>
                <input type = "text" id='contact' name = "contact" placeholder = "Enter your Contact Number" /><br><br><br>
                <button> Save Details </button> <br><br><br>
            </form>
            <p id = "result"></p> 
            <script>
                $("form").submit(function(e){
                    e.preventdefault();

                    $.post(
                        'detail.php';
                    {
                        firstname: $("#fname").val(),
                        lastname: $("#lname").val(),
                        email: $("#email").val(),
                        contact: $("#contact").val()
                    }
                    function(result){

                        if (result == "success"){
                            $("#result").html("Values inserted successfully"); 
                        else{
                            $("#result").html("Values insertion failed");
                         }
                        }
                    );

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Above is my HTML code along with the php. I am not able to use the ajax application as i intended to use.

Comment: first of all don't try to surpass errors using `@`. Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('diaplay_errors',1);` just after `<?php` to get all possible errors

Comment: For this : $stmt->bind_param("sssi",$fname,$lname,$email,$contact)‌​; it shows - '( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\detail.php on line 13'

Comment: obviously i did that :D

Comment: even if i add sufficient space, error is still the same : '( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\detail.php on line 28' i.e. for '$stmt->bind_param("sssi",$fname,$lname,$email,$contact)‌​;'